# QGIS Does Not Contain Filter

Tags: qgis, filter

In QGIS 3.4, how do you perform a does not contain filter? I know how to perform a contains filter, with the LIKE / ILIKE operators, but how do you perform a does not contain filter?

Answer (score 2):

use **NOT**, like in the following example:

```
NOT("your_field" like '%your_string')
```

Comment: thank you. what would the formula be if I have multiple criteria for not contains

Comment: u can concatenate your conditions with the **AND** operator